# A Recurrence Inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, induction, recurrence-relations

Let $I_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^ne^{x-1}dx$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

I want to show that $0<I_n<\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Integrating by parts I've found that $I_n=1-nI_{n-1}$, and I've also evaluated $I_0=1-e^{-1}$.
Clearly $0<1-e^{-1}<1$, so the inequality holds for $n=0$. I've tried proceeding by induction as follows:
Assume $0<I_{n-1}<\frac{1}{n}$, so using the recurrence relation, $0<\frac{1}{n}-\frac{I_n}{n}<\frac{1}{n}$, which implies $0<I_n<1$, which obviously isn't a tight enough bound.
I've also tried writign out the first few values of $I_n$ to find a pattern and solve the recurrence exactly, but couldn't find any recognizable pattern.

I know this is probably a very simple question, but I'd really appreciate some help or a little hint, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure your integration by parts is correct, if the upper limit is really $n$.

Comment: $I_n=n^ne^{n-1}-nI_{n-1}$ is what it should be. However, if $n$ goes to infinity, the integral clearly diverges, so it's not at all clear how you plan to prove your assertion. Unless you have a typo and you mean the upper bound of the integral to be 1?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, the upper limit is supposed to be 1 and has been edited.

Comment: On the interval $(0,1)$, $0<e^{x-1}<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^ne^{x-1}dx<\int_0^1x^ndx={1\over n+1}$$
As for the recurrence, it is interesting, but hardly useful. It seems to diverge for *all* starting values other than yours.